# Compiler instruction reordering

Tags: c++, optimization

```cpp
struct Vec
{
    double x, y, z;
};

Vec vec;
vec.x = 1.0;
vec.y = 2.0;
vec.z = 3.0;
double res = (&vec.x)[2];    // (&vec.x)[2] should be equal to vec.z
```

Value of variable **res** should be equal to 3. But when I turn the optimizations on, the compiler reorders the instructions incorrectly and  **res** contains some rubbish. Some possible reordering examples:

```cpp
vec.x = 1.0;
vec.y = 2.0;
vec.z = 3.0;
res = (&vec.x)[2];    // correct value

vec.x = 1.0;
vec.y = 2.0;
res = (&vec.x)[2];    // incorrect value
vec.z = 3.0;

vec.x = 1.0;
res = (&vec.x)[2];    // incorrect value
vec.y = 2.0;
vec.z = 3.0;
```

Is this a bug in compiler? Or is it not allowed to access struct data members like this?

**EDIT:**

I have just realised that the previous code actually works, sorry for that. But this does not work:

```cpp
Vec vec;
vec.x = 1.0;
vec.y = 2.0;
vec.z = 3.0;
double res = (&vec.x)[i];    // (&vec.x)[i] should be equal to vec.z when i == 2
```

When the variable **i** is not know at compile time, compiler reorders the instructions incorrectly.

Comment: @BatCoder: If it's undefined behavior, it doesn't matter if you can reproduce it or not.

Comment: Javers, what is the meaning of `(&vec.x)[2]`, how do you understand this?

Comment: (&vec.x)[2] takes address of vec.x, adds 2 and dereferences it. It should return the value of vec.z

Comment: If you want array-like behavior, you should overload the subscript operator of your struct (i.e. operator[]) rather than trying to use pointer arithmetic in a way that it can't legally be used.  See: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/

Comment: Original code uses operator[] which does the same thing -- it returns (&x)[i]

Answer (score 22):

You're invoking undefined behavior.  `(&vec.x)[2]` is equivilant to `(&vec.x) + 2`, and the standard (§[expr.add]/4) has the following to say about pointer addition (emphasis mine):

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object<sup>84</sup>, and the
>   array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression.
>   In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
>   array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
>   (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i −
>   n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
>   the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. **If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

See also note 84 referenced above:

> 84) An object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose; see 5.3.1.

Since `vec.x` is not an array, it is considered to be an element of a single-element array.  Thus `vec.x` and `vec.z` are not elements of the same array, and the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from undefined behavior, note that C++ is not forced to allocate these next to each other. If you want to reference them both by index and name, I suggest doing the other way:

```
struct Vec
{
    double elems[3];
    double& x;
    double& y;
    double& z;

    Vec()
    : x( elems[0] ), y( elems[1] ), z( elems[2] )
    {
    }
};
```

If you can't afford the possible (but not necessary) extra space per object, you might as well declare x, y, z as functions returning reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually found a solution which prevents instruction reordering and does not increase size of the Vec struct:

```cpp
struct Vec
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            double x, y, z;
        };
        double data[3];
    };
};

Vec vec;
vec.x = 1.0;
vec.y = 2.0;
vec.z = 3.0;
double res = vec.data[i];
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work? or is it compiler specific behaviour? Did you test with other compilers?

Comment: That's still UB, twice so.

Comment: sizeof(Vec) == 24. The union shares the same memory for x and data[0], y and data[1], z and data[2].